# Kneighbors time series classification

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, time-series, knn

I have a time dataframe which lenght is 60 ( basically my training set ) and I have a time dataframe which length is 5 ( my test set).

I would like to use K-nearaset neighbors and dynamic time warping in order to classify and forecast.

I have found a "tslearn" package,precisely `KNeighborsTimeSeriesClassifier`
but The following error is raised when executing `fit()`:

```
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous-multioutput'
```

This is my piece of code:

```
df_data=data[data.index<"2020-04-29"]
df_train=df_data[['S&P500 %','VIXY %']]
Y_train=df_data[['Spx_Weight','VIXY_Weight']]

df_test=data[data.index>="2020-04-29"][['S&P500 %','VIXY %']]
#
knn_clf = KNeighborsTimeSeriesClassifier(n_neighbors=3, metric="dtw")
knn_clf.fit(df_train, Y_train)
predicted_labels = knn_clf.predict(df_test)
print("\n2. Nearest neighbor classification using DTW")
```

Comment: It needs the same number of features. Not the same number of samples. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and provide a minimum working example.

Comment: I have uploaded my piece of code, thanks